# Unit Testing Objective C Framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, frameworks

Created a new Framework project in Xcode 7.3 and attempting to create a very basic unit test. However I'be been running into a problem when trying to implement my test. My Framework consists of just one class and I'm trying to import my Framework header in my unit test class. My Tests.m file looks like this:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "unit_tested_framework.h"
```

My framework header file contains access to another test class I made that I want to test in my unit test. However I receive the error. `Could not build Module 'unit_tested_framework'` . 
I have not found a solution for this and was wondering if anyone else has encountered the same issue when trying to implement tests for Framework projects in Xcode. This could very well be a project configuration issue in Xcode that I'm overlooking but I'm not sure. Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

probably it is
#import <unit_tested_framework/unit_tested_framework.h>